# Problems with resource leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Operation {
double add(double a, double b){
    double c;
    c = a+b;
    return c;
}
double sub(double a, double b){
    double c;
    c = a-b;
    return c;
}
double mul(double a, double b){
    double c;
    c = a*b;
    return c;
}
double div(double a, double b){
    double c;
    c = a/b;
    return c;
}
}

class Selection{    
static double x,y;
void func(int a){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char b;
    if(a==1)
        b='+';
    else if(a==2)
        b='-';
    else if(a==3)
        b='*';
    else
        b='/';
    System.out.println(">>You have selected "+b+" operator");
    System.out.println(">>Please enter the first operand.");
    x = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(">>Please enter the second operand.");
    y = sc.nextDouble();
 sc.close(); //line 44, this statement gave me a problem.
    }   
}


public class Calculator {
static int select;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public static void main(String [] args){
    Operation op = new Operation();
    Selection sel = new Selection();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean run = true;


    while(run){
        System.out.printf(">>Select Operator\n>>1: +  2: -  3: *  4: /\n");
        select = sc.nextInt();
        double a = sel.x;
        double b = sel.y;
        double result;

        switch(select){
        case 1:
            sel.func(1);
            a = sel.x;
            b = sel.y;
            result = op.add(a, b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" + "+b+" is "+result);
            break;              
        case 2:
            sel.func(2);
            a = sel.x;
            b = sel.y;
            result = op.sub(a,b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" - "+b+" is "+result);
            break;              
        case 3:
            sel.func(3);
            a = sel.x;
            b = sel.y;
            result = op.mul(a,b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" * "+b+" is "+result);
            break;      
        case 4: 
            sel.func(4);
            a = sel.x;
            b = sel.y;
            result = op.div(a,b);
            System.out.println(">>The result of "+a+" / "+b+" is "+result);
            break;  
        default:
            System.out.println(">>Your number is not available, please try again!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }       

        System.out.println(">>Do you want to exit the program(y)?");
        String startOver = sc.next();


        if(startOver.equals("y")){
            run = false;
            System.out.println(">>Thank you for using my program!");
        }else{
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }
sc.close();   //line 111, this works fine i think.
    }
}

}
```

I am a beginner in Java programming and this is a simple "calculator" code for my homework. I wanted my code to be simple yet effective, and worked very hard on it. After checking the codes, a warning message popped up saying "Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed". I knew it would still run fine without adding "sc.close();", but I wanted my program to be perfect and added the "sc.close();" statements to line 44 and  111. After adding the statements, the warning about resource leaks disappeared, but when I run the code, there is a time when the program asks for another calculation, at right there, a debug console pops up.

I am not sure why a debug console would pop up there, what do you think the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be seeing a 'Potential resource leak...' warning, if not please open a bug.
The main issue here is that the compiler does not know what 'close(..)' method does. It may or may not close the resource. (Note that the compiler does not perform inter-procedural analysis)
You can choose to ignore 'Potential resource leak' warnings. ('Resource leak' warnings are guaranteed to be correct however the 'Potential... ' ones are not)
More details on the resource leak analysis can be found here - http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm&cp=1_3_9_1

EDIT: A word on 'Resource leak' vs 'Potential resource leak'

The idea is that all reported 'Resource leak' warnings are guaranteed to be correct but may not be 'all' the resource leaks in the code base.
'Potential resource leaks' are well... potential problems. Some developers turn on 'Potential...' warnings when they know something is going wrong but they do not know where. In such cases potential warnings help to narrow down the search. Some other developers just go over potential warnings from time to time to see if there is a real problem there.
Ideally we would want the compiler to give us the complete and correct set of problems, but there are limitations in achieving that :-)